# How to fix producer-consumer program so that both threads terminate when counter reaches 10?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

I am trying to write a small program in C that implements the producer-consumer approach for two threads. I intend for it to share one mutex and two condition variables to make a counting variable count from 0 to 10. I have some problems with what I have now, as it is still running the consumer thread after a message is sent for the program to end when the latter needs to be the last line of output. I have the threads down that I needed to use, but how can I fix what is going on here?

Current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIZE 10
pthread_mutex_t myMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t myCond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t myCond2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int myCount = 0;

void print_mutex_status(const char* thread, const char* status) {
    printf("%s: myMutex %s\n", thread, status);
}

void print_cond_status(const char* thread, const char* cond) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", thread, cond);
}

void* producer_thread(void* arg) {
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
        print_mutex_status("PRODUCER", "locked");
        while (myCount == SIZE) {
            print_cond_status("PRODUCER", "waiting on myCond1");
            pthread_cond_wait(&myCond1, &myMutex);
        }
        // Produce an item
        printf("myCount: %d -> %d\n", myCount, myCount + 1);
        myCount++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
        print_mutex_status("PRODUCER", "unlocked");
        pthread_cond_signal(&myCond2);
        print_cond_status("PRODUCER", "signaling myCond2");
        if (myCount == SIZE) {
            printf("PROGRAM END\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // Corrected line to terminate the program
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* consumer_thread(void* arg) {
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
        print_mutex_status("CONSUMER", "locked");
        while (myCount == 0) {
            print_cond_status("CONSUMER", "waiting on myCond2");
            pthread_cond_wait(&myCond2, &myMutex);
        }
        // Consume an item
        printf("myCount: %d -> %d\n", myCount, myCount - 1);
        myCount--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
        print_mutex_status("CONSUMER", "unlocked");
        pthread_cond_signal(&myCond1);
        print_cond_status("CONSUMER", "signaling myCond1");
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    printf("PROGRAM START\n");
    pthread_t producer, consumer;
    if (pthread_create(&producer, NULL, producer_thread, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("Error creating producer thread");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, consumer_thread, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("Error creating consumer thread");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("CONSUMER THREAD CREATED\n");
    pthread_join(producer, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&myCond1);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&myCond2);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output (which actually runs through multiple lines I cannot fit in here...

```
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 0
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 0 -> 1
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 1 -> 2
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 2 -> 3
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 3 -> 4
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 4 -> 5
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 5 -> 6
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 6 -> 7
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 7 -> 8
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 8 -> 9
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
PRODUCER: myMutex locked
myCount: 9 -> 10
PRODUCER: myMutex unlocked
PRODUCER: signaling myCond2
PROGRAM END
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
CONSUMER: signaling myCond1
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
```

Once the program begins, a line should say "PROGRAM START", which is already hard to find. Also, the consumer thread needs to be created before the second increment, again hard to find. In addition, "PROGRAM END" is supposed to be the last line, not the fourth to last line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a number of problems in your code.

When the producer prints "PROGRAM END", the consumer thread is still running so it can print messages after the "PROGRAM END" was printed. If you want "PROGRAM END" to be the last printed message, you must make sure that the consumer thread is stopped before printing "PROGRAM END". In other words - you need to do a `pthread_join` on the consumer thread first.

That leads to another problem. The current consumer thread can't end. There is no exit condition in the code. You need to add that. Perhaps like:

```
    if (myCount == SIZE) {
        printf("CONSUMER END\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    printf("myCount: %d -> %d\n", myCount, myCount - 1);
    myCount--;
```

Notice the use of `pthread_exit`. In the producer thread you should also use `pthread_exit` instead of `exit`.

I would probably move the print of "PROGRAM END" to `main` instead of doing it in the producer thread. Something like this in `main`:

```
pthread_join(producer, NULL);
pthread_join(consumer, NULL);
printf("PROGRAM END\n");
```

In the producer thread you have a problem here:

```
if (myCount == SIZE) {
```

Here you access the shared variable without a lock.

And in this code

```
    while (myCount == SIZE) {
        print_cond_status("PRODUCER", "waiting on myCond1");
        pthread_cond_wait(&myCond1, &myMutex);
    }
```

the condition (i.e. `myCount == SIZE`) will never be true.

Finally it's worth to mention that the program may turn forever. You can't be sure that `myCount` will reach `SIZE`. For each increment made by the producer, the consumer may do a decrement, i.e. `myCount` could change like "0 1 0 1 0 1 0 ...." forever.